# How to pass the output of CSS Selector to beautiful soup?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape some webpages, I'm using a Chrome extension called "SelectorGadget". its a CSS selector. Now for example for this URL: http://www.www2015.it/documents/proceedings/forms/proceedings.htm
the CSS selector gives me this output for the list of papers: *tr~ tr+ tr td+ td a* Now, the problem is I cannot figure out that how can I pass this output to beautiful soup. In the following lines, the .select() does not recognize these selectors!

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.www2015.it/documents/proceedings/forms/proceedings.htm")
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content)
soup.select("tr~ tr+ tr td+ td a")
```

Comment: You can post your code? of what you have until now?

Comment: Did you mean `.select(...)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I use .select() it says: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "tr~"

Comment: Then use supported and valid selectors, but that's how you use selectors in BS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean the selector gadget returns invalid selectors?

Comment: ...or unsupported ones. Also not terribly useful ones, if the result of `$("tr~ tr+ tr td+ td a")` in the console is to be believed!

Comment: @jonrsharpe So, do you suggest a better CSS selector! Or any other way that I can select the list of papres from that webpage and pass them to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is - `BeautifulSoup` has a [very limited CSS selector syntax support](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). In your case, going sideways with `~` or `+` is not going to work as is.

If you are looking to match the `pdf` links on this page, I would use the following selector:

```
soup.select("a[href$=pdf]")  # get the links where href ends with "pdf"
```

Comment: Do you know any scarper such that it would be able to handle these selectors?

Comment: @RaminZahedi yup, look into lxml.cssselect.